# How to display array element by expression

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and in my **controller** I have some arrays, for example:

```
$scope.users[] = {
  id: 0,
  name: "John",
  surname: "Doe"  
};

$scope.cars[] = {
  id: 0,
  userid: 0,
  color: "blue"
};
```

then in **view**, I want to display some data, for example:

```
<div class="...">{{ cars[0].color }}</div>
```

this working fine. But now, I want to display name of the users, `where cars.userid = users.id`. I tried something like this:

```
<div class="...">{{ users.name | filter: {users.id:cars.userid} }}</div>
```

but it throws an error of course. I am not sure, if I can use filters this way, or if I must write my own function to the controller, which return the right user name, something like:

```
$scope.showUserName = function(id) {
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
    if(id == $scope.users[i].id) {
      return $scope.users[i].name;
    }
  }
}
```

and then in my view:

```
<div class="...">{{ showUserName(cars.userid) }}</div>
```

Thank you for explanation.

Comment: An now, you want to use filter for it?

Comment: I think, that is faster then write X separately functions ... bcs I need to merge data between Y arrays :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

**First, define your filter like this**

```
app.filter('carUser', function() {  //register the filter
    return function(carId, users) { //first arg = input, subsequent argument = others
        for(var key in users)
            if(users[key].id === carId)
                return users[key].name;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- users come from $scope.users -->
<div>The user of {{ cars[0].name }} is {{ cars[0].userId | carUser:users }}</div>
```

Comment: it looks good, but how can I define the array in the filter? In your example I see error "users not defined"

Comment: @pes502 See edit.  You just pass users in with `carUser:users`.  Then in your filter implementation, the first argument is always the input.  Subsequent arguments are what you pass in:  `filterName:arg1:arg2:arg3:etc....`

Comment: thank you man, I edited your code a little bit and its working as I expected and this is what I need :) btw your nick is too OP